# VB.net has process finished running

Tags: vb.net

I have this code which prints files in vb.net:

```
' Create object, passing in text
                Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo
                psi.UseShellExecute = True
                psi.Verb = "print"
                psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                psi.FileName = fi.FullName
                Process.Start(psi)
```

i want to be able to run more code once the printing process has completed, how can i see if it has completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you most likely want to wait for the process to finish. Try this:

```
Dim p = Process.Start("calc.exe")
p.WaitForExit()
```

If you really don't want to wait but just check for completion try this:

```
If p.HasExited() Then
  ' do something
End If
```